# How to search and move files from one path to another C++?

Tags: c++, file, path

I'm trying to search all files that follow this pattern "`console-*`" and move them to another path on my machine if they exist. (For example from: `/documents/fs/pstore` to `/sdk/sys/kernel_dump/`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int dirExists(const char *pathname)
{
   struct stat info;

   if( stat( pathname, &info ) != 0 )
      return 0; //  printf( "cannot access %s\n", pathname );
   else if( info.st_mode & S_IFDIR )  // S_ISDIR() doesn't exist on my windows 
      return 1; //  printf( "%s is a directory\n", pathname );
   else
      return 0; //  printf( "%s is no directory\n", pathname );
}

int main()
{
    const char *path = "/documents/fs/pstore";
    if(dirExists(path))
        system("mv /documents/fs/pstore/console-* /sdk/sys/kernel_dump/ ");
    else
        printf( "error" );

    return 0;
}
```

I've experienced with the code above, but it does not seem to work properly, should I try another approach, maybe with the [rename()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) function? (I'm working on Linux)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: C++17 std::filesystem?

Comment: I'm restricted to C++14

Comment: Please **DO NOT** tag C++ questions with C, this is bad tagging

Comment: If `boost` is okay then have a look at [`boost.filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/filesystem/).

Answer (score 0):

You can call glob() and rename() C functions in Linux if C++17's std::filesystem is not an option for you. glob() gives you the list of files that matches globbing pattern like *, ? and []. However, rename() may fail if the mount position of from and to path are not identical. In this case, you should create your own copy and remove file function.